# Ansible - how to run different playbook/module?

Tags: ansible

I am newbie to ansible and i am looking for help on ansible playbook.

My sample architecture (folder location)

```
Action1

- roles
  - module1_action1
      - tasks
      - templates
  - module2_action2
      - tasks
      - templates
  - module3_action3
      - tasks
      - templates
  - action1.yml


Action2

- roles
  - module4_action4
      - tasks
      - templates
  - action2.yml
```

Here is my question: How can i use action2.yml to execute Action1's module2_action2?

Thank so much for your help.

LAU

Answer (score 0):

Set [roles_path](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_configuration.html#roles-path) in `ansible.cfg` to include `Action1/roles` and `Action2/roles`.

This way you can access action1's roles from actions2 playbook.

Comment: I go the answer and it is very easy, just edit the action2.yml and roles like below. 

roles:  
    - role: ../Action1/roles/module2_action2